# How do I calculate number of changes in work item fields

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I need to add a filed to work item that count number of changes in a another filed, let say I have a filed called EndDate so I need a way to calculate how many times this filed is changed and present it as filed EndDateChangeCount in order to query based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default work item rules do not support count the number of times based on any another work item field be changed.

For this scenario, you can submit it as a suggestion [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/Azure+DevOps.html). Our PM will kindly review any suggestion.

As a workaround, if your company has the Analytics Services turned on and available to users, [then you could use Excel's Power Pivot tools to query the cube directly.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/?view=tfs-2018)

**NOTE**: The TFS Warehouse and Analytics Cube haven't seen major updates since their introduction in 2010 and are being replaced by the new OData based Analytics Service in Azure Devops. A sample for your reference:

```
SELECT [WorkItemSK]
      ,[WorkItem]
      ,[System_Id]
      ,[System_Title]
      ,[System_State]
      ,[System_Rev]
      ,[System_ChangedBy]
      ,[System_Reason]
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[WorkItemHistoryView]
  where 
  System_Id = 24 --This is the ID from TFS for the WIT  
and xxx
```

Another way you can use the REST API or Client API to *get all revisions of a work item*. Iterate over the revisions and check whether the EndDate field has been changed.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, it save our lot times